# AlarmManager is not firing on Scheduled time?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I have implemented alarManager in my android application. This repeat schedule time of alarm is 5 second. But instead of 5 second alarm repeat after one minute.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

intent.putExtra(Constants.Extra.SERVICE_TYPE, Constants.Extra.SERVICE_TRIGGER);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123456789, intent, 0);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000, pendingIntent);
```

receiver class

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
            String type = extras.getString(Constants.Extra.SERVICE_TYPE);

            if(type != null && type.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.Extra.SERVICE_TRIGGER)){

                //Triger  

            }
        }
    }
```

manifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Receivers -->
<receiver android:name=".receiver.ServiceTrigger">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.project.ServiceTrigger" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: `AlarmManager` isn't meant to be used for intervals that short.

Comment: @MikeM. can you tell me what can i use for short interval of time except Timer

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

Use this

```
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
```

Instead of

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000, pendingIntent);
```

Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

As of Android 5.1 (API version 22) there is a minimum period of 1 minute for repeating alarms. If you need to do work within one minute, just set the alarm directly, then set the next one from that alarm's handler, etc. If you need to do work within 5 seconds (for example), post it to a Handler instead of using the AlarmManager.

Good documetion here :

https://en.proft.me/2017/05/7/scheduling-operations-alarmmanager-android/

Answer (score 1):

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
int ALARM_TYPE = AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(ALARM_TYPE, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    am.setExact(ALARM_TYPE, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
else
    am.set(ALARM_TYPE, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```